# When I tried to run my Django server I faced the following problem

Tags: python, django, server, request

I am trying to run my Django server and I am facing the following issue. So, I am pretty new on Django, then Let me know if you need any additional information. This code is really complex to me and I am challenging myself to run multiples applications at the same time.

```
    Environment:
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

    Django Version: 2.2.2
    Python Version: 3.6.4
    Installed Applications:
    ['registration',
     'mailqueue',
     'el_pagination',
     'social_django',
     'django_inlinecss',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'main',
     'users']
    Installed Middleware:
    ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware']
```

> ```
> Traceback:
>     File "/home/rnominato/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
>       34.             response = get_response(request)
>     File "/home/rnominato/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>       115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/home/rnominato/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
>       113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/home/rnominato/PycharmProjects/Liben_Feb_2020/main/decorators.py" in wrap
>       20.         mode = Mode.objects.get(id=1)
>     File "/home/rnominato/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
>       82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/rnominato/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
>       408.                 self.model._meta.object_name
>     Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /
>     Exception Value: Mode matching query does not exist.
> ```

Comment: Your code is looking for a specific `Mode` object that does not exist.

Comment: Following on from @KlausD.'s comment - your traceback is telling you that you're running this query: `mode = Mode.objects.get(id=1)`, and there is no Mode with that id.

Comment: Sure. Any extra tip to solve this problem? I treid to remove this line, but it is not working.